# Can't get several tiny_mce editors on a page, only one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I use Ruby on Rails 2.3 and gem 'tiny_mce'

Gem uses TinyMCE 3.4

Gem generates script on my page

```
tinyMCE.init({
  editor_selector : 'mceEditor',
  mode : 'textareas'
});
```

Next, I have several textareas with class 'mceEditor'. But actually editor appears only at first textarea.

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give all of your textareas different ids!

Comment: editor_selector option must specify css class http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:editor_selector

Comment: glad to have been able to help